# Long Running Query in Entity Framework with multiple table joins

Tags: entity-framework

I have a query that joins about 10 tables some that are self referencing tables. I use an "IN" statement for the conditional on the ID column (indexed) of the top most table.

```
var aryOrderId = DetermineOrdersToGet(); //Logic to determine what orderids to get
var result = dbContext.Orders.Where(o=>aryOrderId.Contains(o.id)
    .Include(o=>o.Customer)
    .Include(o=>o.Items.Select(oi=>oi.ItemAttributes))
    .Include(o=>o.Items.Select(oi=>oi.Dimensions))
    .Include(o=>o.CustomOptions.Select(oc => oc.CustomOptions1))
.....A Bunch more.....
    .ToList();
```

I would like to figure out a way to speed this up without redesigning my tables and flattening out the structure. Currently 50-200 records take 10-20 seconds.

This data can be read only.  I don't need to update these records.

1. Can I convert this to a stored procedure?
2. How hard is this to do?
3. Will I be able to get noticeable performance gains?

Comment: Do you really need _every_ column from every one of those tables?  Because with all these `Include` statements, the generated SQL query is `SELECT * FROM ...` which is generally not good practice when writing SQL queries.  You may want to add a `.Select()` call just before the `.ToList()` to select specific columns you need.

Comment: It's really easy to map a stored procedure, and that's how I would probably do this.  Are you using code-first, model-first, or db first?

Comment: @EricH I am using db first.  I can get the outputted sql when I run this in debug mode.  Is there a website link you can recommend or a search term?

Comment: @jtate  I wish I could eliminate some of these but it is for the order detail output.  I need all the fields unfortunately.

Comment: @Dan In that case, you should be able to map it easily.  I'll add some simple instructions to my answer.

Comment: @Dan My apologies, as I've only just picked up on the fact that you're wanting to retain the entire graph of entities.  It's not really possible with a single mapped stored procedure as far as I know.  However if you're willing to flatten the data the SP mapping will really help you.

Comment: @erich I switched this from include to select and it sped up the call a lot.  I have not tested any other layers of the application yet to make sure this works as expected.  But it is a start.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the slower parts of the database query is the transport of the selected data from the DBMS to your local process. Hence it is wise to select only the properties you actually plan to use.

For example, it seems that an `Order` has zero or more `ItemAttributes`. Evey `ItemAttribute` belongs to exactly one `Order`, using a foreign key `OrderId`.

If you fetch all `Orders` with Id in `ArryOrderId`, each order with its thousand `ItemAttributes`, you know that every `ItemAttribute` will have a foreign key `OrderId` with the same value as the Id of the Order that it belongs to. It is a waste to send 1000 times the same value.

> When querying data using entity framework, always use Select. Select only the properties yo actually plan to use. Only use Include if you intend to change the fetched objects.

```
var result = dbContext.Orders
    .Where(order=>aryOrderId.Contains(order.id)
    .Select(order => new
    {   // select only the properties you plan to use:
        Id = order.Id,
        ...
        Customer = order.Customer.Select(customer => new
        {   // again: only the properties you plan to use
            Id = order.Customer.Id,
            Name = order.Customer.Name,
            ...
        },
        ItemAttributes = order.ItemAttributes.Select(itemAttribute => new
        {
            ...
        })
        .ToList(),
        Dimensions = order.Dimensions.Select(dimension => new
        {
            ...
        })
        .ToList(),
        ....A Bunch more.....
})
.ToList();
```

If after selecting only the properties that you actually plan to use, the query still takes too long, think again: do I really need all these properties.

Another solution to limit the execution time is fetching the date 'per page', using Skip / Take. The danger is of course that when you are viewing page 10, the data of page 1 might be changed in a way that page 10 should be interpreted differently.

Comment: I rewrote the whole query and it runs 5 times faster now.  I am still have more tests to run but this is a great improvement.

Answer (score 1):

As jtate mentions, if you don't need everything from the joined tables, don't include them. Instead, utilize `.Select()` to retrieve just the data you want from the entity and it's associated relationships.

I.e.

```
var query = dbContext.Orders
  .Where(x => aryOrderId.Contains(x => x.OrderId))
  .Select(x => new 
  {
     x.OrderId,
     x.OrderNumber,
     OrderItems = x.Items.Select(i => new 
     {
       i.ItemId,
       Attributes = i.Attributes.Select(a => a.AttributeName).ToList(),
       Dimensions = i.Dimensions.Select(d => new {d.DimensionId, d.Name}).ToList(),
     }).ToList(),
     // ...
   }).ToList();
```

You can structure the query, or queries however you like to find an optimal result.

Alternatively you can consider utilizing a view on the database and binding an entity to the view. This option works well for read-only views of data. Provided you include the relevant IDs you can always retrieve the applicable "real" entities at any time to load a details page or perform an action/update against the entity.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your 3 questions.  Yes, you can use a stored procedure and that's what I would do in this situation.  It is not hard at all; EF makes it quite simple.  You can either have it return a new complex type or you can map it to an entity.  Since you're saying the data can be readonly, you probably are okay with a basic function import returning a complex type (EF's default behavior).  Either way, you will have noticeable performance gains.

For db-first, see http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Basically, you'll follow these steps.

1. Create the stored procedure on your database
2. Update the model from the database.  When it asks which objects to include, you should be able to select your stored procedure.
3. Click Finish.  EF will generate a complex type that has all the properties returned by your stored procedure, and it will add a signature to your context for executing the stored procedure, so it can be called like this: `var results = myContext.myProcedure(param1, param2);` There are screenshots of this at the link above.
4. You can also go in and modify the model to customize the details, such as the name of the complex type and the name of the function (by default the function will match the name of the SP and will return an `ObjectResult<T>` where T is your complex type, which will be the name of the procedure with "_Result" as a suffix).

Comment: Also, be aware that modifying the stored procedure once it's imported like this is kind of a pain, as the complex type will not automatically be updated with the modified stored procedure output.  You have to go add the scalar properties to the complex type manually (unless someone knows something I don't).  Just a heads up.